# Class 'Silex\Provider\PDO' not found. How to solve?

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine, silex

I'm using Silex as well as Doctrine. It's worked great for me for everything until I needed to bindValue for a LIMIT value. PDO's default behavior is to insert quotes around the number, which is obviously not workable. So, the solution is to set the `data_type` parameter. Unfortunately, it throws an error.

**My Code**

```
$start_num = 3;
$stmt = $app['db']->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT ?,10');
$stmt->bindValue(1, $start_num, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**The Error**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Silex\Provider\PDO' not found in ...
```

Most answers I've found regarding this issue say that it's a telltale sign of PDO not being compiled/enabled, however I've been using Doctrine (which relies on PDO?) successfully for a while with no problem.

Is this an issue with Doctrine? Is there something I'm doing wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a namespacing issue, if this code is in a class under the `Silex\Provider` namespace

Try

```
\PDO::PARAM_INT
```